# php5 shorthand variables

Tags: php

I have seen most of the developers use `$name` instead of `$_GET['name']` and `$domain` instead of `$_POST['domain']`, is this shorthand by php5 and is it safe or any documentation for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because they're using the (ill-advised and now thankfully deprecated) `register_globals` feature. (See the PHP manual section on [Using Register Globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) for the full low-down including security related information.)

I'd *really* recommend not using this approach and explicitly using the $_POST or $_GET variables instead, as there's a potential world of security issues that await you otherwise.

Comment: Further, if you're reading code that takes advantage of `register_globals`, you should be aware that the code in question is ancient and outdated.  If the code you're reading is from a tutorial, I'd advise no longer trusting the site hosting it.  Really, you shouldn't trust any PHP tutorials older then 3-4 years...

Comment: @Charles So, very, very, true. :-)

Comment: 'oscommerce' still requires register_globals out-of-the-box, though there is a module that fixes that. But simply seeing that moronic requirement was enough to nuke that system from my list of ecommerce solutions I was testing for a client.

Comment: @Charles I have seen this approach on many open source projects, but this doesn't work at my VPS.

Comment: @seoppc Be thankful that this is the case. It's a bad practice that *really* shouldn't be propagated. As the PHP website itself states "**Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.**" :-)

Comment: @Marc I occasionally remember some of the internal aspects of osCommerce and break out in a cold sweat. ;-)

Comment: @seoppc, the use of `register_globals` in *any* code is a sure sign that you don't want to use it, open source or not.

Comment: @seoppc No problems - hope all goes well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The examples you listed are only available if `register_globals` is set. It is deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and should not be used as it is a security risk among other things.

Read more from the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php